# PDF to TIFF free library in Windows?

Tags: windows, pdf, tiff

i've got a hundred pages long high quality PDF (66MB) that needs to be converted to TIFF format (300 dpi, as high quality as possible :P).

I've tried Imagemagick/ghostscript, jpedal, Poppler, XPDF but they all produce different results due to the strange gradient of the PDF itself (blame the designers) and some actually take forever....

Does any one know any alternatives that i can try?

Thanks in advance,
M.

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't have an answer, but out of curiosity, why are do you need to convert them to TIFF? I have customers that often want TIFF and I'm not sure why they need TIFF. For faxing maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) does a pretty good job reading PDF files. Here's a [Windows installer](http://gimp-win.sourceforge.net/).

The GIMP will load each page of the PDF into its own layer, so you'll have to export each one as a TIFF. Luckily, [this can be automated](http://uzebox.org/wiki/index.php?title=Layer_Export_GIMP_Script). I have no experience with the linked script, but if it doesn't suit your needs then it shouldn't be hard to modify it or write a quick script of your own to export each layer as a TIFF image.

Comment: The GIMP uses Ghostscript. If GS didn't work, GIMP probably won't either.

Comment: I think newer versions of GIMP use Poppler instead

Comment: Poppler is even worse when it comes to little tweaks in PDFs. I don't want to rule it out (no flames please: I am a fan of GIMP and GhostScript and all), it's worth a try, but I'm pessimistic.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Adobe Reader to flatten your PDF to PostScript (newer versions do that from the command line, but since it's just one file, you can print to a PS file) before going through Ghostscript. That might remove some weird PDF issues.

Comment: as I added, since it's just one PDF, you can just use Print to File.

Comment: PostScript doesn't support everything that PDF does, but this seems like a good idea to me. If the resulting PostScript is an accurate reproduction of the PDF then you have a much better chance of getting a high-quality rasterization from PostScript than PDF.

Comment: You're right as to the features of PS versus PDF, but Adobe Reader (sort of being the reference implementation) does a good job at "downconverting" (flattening) while keeping the actual "look" of the PDF document. Since it's going to be rastered, that's fine. BTW, I just checked, it seems like the Windows version of Adobe Reader doesn't do command line.